# how to merge pd.to_json file and dictionary?

Tags: python

this is the transformed json file that using pd.to_json
[image]

and this is dictionary format
[image]

I want these two looks like this
[image]

I forced to merge those with like

```
print('['+str(dict({'Message1':'Hello','Message2':'word'}))+','+df1[1:])
```

but the java won't accept this format. Maybe I have to send the format with pd.to_json..

Comment: What do you mean by "Java won't accept this format"?

Comment: I need to return this code to java, but java occurs a error. code below doesn't occur an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` not `pd.DataFrame.to_json`, then it's simply a matter of:

```
print([{'Message1':'Hello','Message2':'word'}, *df.to_dict('records')])
```

Or if it's very particular about the output:

```
import json

d = {'Message1':'Hello','Message2':'word'}

out = [d, *df.to_dict('records')]
print(json.dumps(out))
```

Comment: thank you but I tried this for seconds ago, I need to transform dict to json

Comment: `dict` is basically `json`... if you need it to be "*pure*" json, use the `json` module like shown.